# Do you know why search icon is not showing with white background color and the dropdowns are not aligned at right?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have a layout that has a header and a fotoer and between header and footer there are some list items with posts. Im using bootstrap, I want the header to look like this:

[image]

But its not working, its showing like this: https://jsfiddle.net/83vnj5ru/1/.

The search icon dont have a background white color and the Filter 1 and Filter 2 dropdowns are not aligned at the right like in the image. Do you know why?

HTML:

```
<div class="container py-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <ul class="list-group forum">
        <li class="list-group-item bg-custom-light2 py-4">
          <div class="row">
            <form class="col-5">
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
                  </div>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1"
                         aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Search">
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="col-7 text-right">
            <div class="dropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle"  id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Filter 1
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">item1</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Filter 2
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">item1</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">list item 1</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">list item 2</li>

        <li class="list-group-item bg-custom-light2 py-4">container footer</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bg-custom-light2{
  background-color: #fafafa;
}
.input-group-text, .input-group-prepend{
  background-color:none;
}
.input-group-text{
  color:gray;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if it helps you

```css
.bg-custom-light2{
  background-color: #fafafa;
}
.input-group-text, .input-group-prepend{
  background-color:none;
}
.input-group-text{
  color:gray;
}

.filters{
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

.search-icon{
  background-color: #ffffff !important;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da !important;
  border-right: 1px solid transparent !important;
}

.search-input{
  border-left: 1px solid transparent !important;  
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container py-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <ul class="list-group forum">
        <li class="list-group-item bg-custom-light2 py-4">
          <div class="row">
            <form class="col-5">
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text search-icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
                  </div>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control search-input" id="exampleInputEmail1"
                         aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Search">
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          <div class="col-7 text-right">
            <div class="dropdown filters">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle"  id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Filter 1
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">item1</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown filters">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Filter 2
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">item1</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">list item 1</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">list item 2</li>

        <li class="list-group-item bg-custom-light2 py-4">container footer</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know why the search form and the filters are not vertically aligned at center? For example there is more space above the search form than below the search form.

Comment: See this topic to get more information about vertical alignment of elements in a div: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79461/vertical-alignment-of-elements-in-a-div